# The most optimized way to add ssl support to python-for-android

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to use [websocket-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client) in my Kivy project. As you know it requires `ssl`. Adding `openssl` to buildozer requirements adds about 3`mb` to the apk size, which is a headache. The question: is there a way to build the python that is going to run on android with `--with-ssl` option? If there is, does it increase the package size too? What's the best approach here?